# Convert NULL datetime to Blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, null

I would like to convert a datetime field to varchar so I can show a blank or a message when the date is NULL.
This is what I have so far:

```
select
isnull(us.Date,0) as USDate,
isnull(au.Date,0) as AUDate
from ustable us
left join autable au
on us.column=au.column
```

Right now this is showing:

```
USDATE 
2014-10-24 10:29:07.450
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

I would like to be able to make the "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000" varchar so I can write a message or show a true blank.

Comment: I would suggest doing this type of formatting int the front end instead of in sql. Let your application handle the display.

Answer (score 10):

The simplest line of code I've found for what you're trying to accomplish is as follows.

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),us.Date,121),'') as USDate,
ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),au.Date,121),'') as AUDate,
```

I have tested this and verified that it works.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Case` AND `CONVERT` like this -

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN us.Date IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), us.Date, 121) END AS USDate,
CASE WHEN au.Date IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), au.Date, 121) END AS AUDate
FROM ustable us
left join autable au
on us.column=au.column
```

Comment: This will actually output `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`.

Comment: Is the second `CASE` missing an `END` ?

Answer (score 1):

To do it in SQL:

Change your `SELECT` statement to incorporate a `WHEN`...`THEN` clause:

```
CASE us.Date 
  WHEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN ''
  WHEN NULL THEN ''
  ELSE us.Date
END as USDate,
CASE au.Date 
  WHEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN ''
  WHEN NULL THEN ''
  ELSE au.Date
END as AUDate
```

If you have front-end code, then you could just implement the functionality on the front-end without changing your SQL code.

Comment: Two problems: (1) they want an empty string when the date in the table is NULL, not 1900-01-01 (2) this returns NULL even when the date actually has a valid value (other than 1900-01-01).

Comment: You were correct. I could not test this at the time because I didn't have access to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Given a column defined like this:

```
date_of_birth datetime null
```

You can simply say

```
select date_of_birth = coalesce( convert(varchar(32),date_of_birth) , '' )
from some_table_with_a_nullable_datetime_column
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NVL() function ...

> You can use the NVL function to convert an expression that evaluates
>   to NULL to a value that you specify. The NVL function accepts two
>   arguments: the first argument takes the name of the expression to be
>   evaluated; the second argument specifies the value that the function
>   returns when the first argument evaluates to NULL. If the first
>   argument does not evaluate to NULL, the function returns the value of
>   the first argument.

For example:

```
select
nvl(us.Date,'') as USDate,
nvl(au.Date,'') as AUDate
from ustable us
left join autable au
on us.column=au.column
```

Or put anything you want as the Default:

```
select
nvl(us.Date,'this was a NULL') as USDate,
nvl(au.Date,'this was a NULL') as AUDate
from ustable us
left join autable au
on us.column=au.column
```

Comment: OP indicates this is SQL Server (MS).  `NVL` is an Oracle function.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
select
CONVERT(varchar(50), isnull(us.Date,0)) as USDate,
CONVERT(varchar(50), isnull(au.Date,0)) as AUDate
from ustable us
left join autable au
on us.column=au.column
```

You'll want to change the size of the varchar depending upon your date format.  Also, CONVERT takes a third parameter that will allow you to change the format of your string.

Comment: This returns `Jan  1 1900 12:00AM` on my system, not `''`.

Comment: "isnull(us.Date,0)" should return an integer Zero.  Then the Convert statement should turn that into a string "0".  What do you get if you replace the second parameter of the IsNull statement with an empty string?

Comment: If `us.Date` is date/datetime etc., it does not. Did you ***try it***?

Comment: Apologies.  I ran, "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ISNULL(Null,0));" and got my answer.  Which is in fact different when the null comes from a datetime column or variable as opposed to a hard-coded value.

Answer (score 0):

```
select null USDate, NUll AUDate
from ustable us
left join autable au on us.column=au.column
```

It's work try it, it will show column value should be null.